# Windows command output getting cut short

Tags: batch-file, grep

I'm writing a batch file that uses GNU grep for Windows to analyze output from a program.

The command I am struggling with is intended to find multiple matches that span more than one line. When I run this single command within my batch file, I get the expected output.

```
someprogram.exe | grep -PZo "(?s)Start.*?End"

Start
...
End
Start
...
End
Start
...
End
```

However, the moment I try to pipe this into something else (or if I run the command in command prompt), only one of the matches is getting through:

```
someprogram.exe | grep -PZo "(?s)Start.*?End" | more

Start
...
End
```

However, if each match only spans one line, then I don't ever encounter this problem.

```
Start...End
Start...End
Start...End
```

I suspect that this may have to do with how grep handles newlines, but no documentation has been helpful. Can someone please explain what is happening and give perhaps give me a workaround?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you try to filter the `cmd.exe` `dir` command? What specifically are you trying to find in the output?

Comment: For a workaround, you could try using a better scripting language, like Python or Ruby. Then you wouldn't have to use grep at all.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Curiously enough,
 
    `dir | grep -PZo "(?s)bat.*?bat"`

always will show all output. Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: Are you using GNU `more`, or the `more` in system32?  Try running `where more` to see which it's getting.

Comment: I recommend PowerShell anyway...

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Good advice for any situation involving CMD, but in this case, it wouldn't help.  The problem is endemic to the difference between pipe handling in UNIX vs Windows.

Comment: @RyanBemrose My examples use system\32 more, but my actual use case is to pipe into grep again to do further matching. I would also rather stick to a batch solution, because of my project's established conventions...

Comment: In PowerShell we would use `Select-String` rather than `grep`. There is little need (or possibly no need at all) for any unix tools in this case.

Comment: Try removing `-Z` from grep options... Perhaps `more` is considering `\0` as `EOF`...